# How to add '.' before every consonant in a string?

Tags: java, string, character

I'm quite new to Java, I found a question in `codeforces.com` about deleting all vowels from the string and add dot(.) before every consonant. I already find how to delete all of the vowels, but not yet on how to add dot before every consonant. Please help me :) Thank you

```
public class Stringprob{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;
        word = s.next();
        word = word.replaceAll("[aeiouyAEIOUY]","");
        //the problem says that 'Y' is a vowel too
        word = insert("[^aeiouyAEIOUY]", ".");
        //here is where I lost it all
        System.out.println(word);
        }
}
```

Sorry the code is really messy, I'm really new to Java.

Source : [String Task - codeforces.com](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/118/A)

Comment: Please post your code and where it is missing something, what the sample input and outputs are.

Comment: @luk2302 I'm sorry I'm new to stack overflow, how to add the code to look like actual code and not like paragraph?

Comment: by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `capture group ()` and `$1` as replacement

1.) Remove all vowels `[aeiouyYAEIOU]`

2.) Only consonants will be left after applying step 1 so , capture every character using `([a-zA-Z])` and replace it with a `.$1` where `.` is a dot and `$1` the character itself

**Note :** `[a-zA-Z]` will be more efficient in terms of performance because this will only capture character where as `([^aeiouyAEIOUY])` will match anything other than vowels means it can also match special character and numbers like `@#$%^&*12346`.

```
 word  = word .replaceAll("[aeiouyYAEIOU]","");
 word = word.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])", ".$1");
```

Or to match and add `.` with special characters and numbers as well

```
 word  = word .replaceAll("[aeiouyYAEIOU]","");
 word = word.replaceAll("([^aeiouyAEIOUY])", ".$1");
```

`([^aeiouyAEIOUY])` : capture all consonants  and use replacement as `.$1` where `$1` represents the captured consonant

`[^aeiouyAEIOUY]` : `^` mean not in the `[]`

```
    String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAEIOUY";

    // replace all vowels 
    s = s.replaceAll("[aeiouyYAEIOU]","");
    s = s.replaceAll("([a-zA-z])", ".$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output :

```
.b.c.d.f.g.h.j.k.l.m.n.p.q.r.s.t.v.w.x.z
```

---

just for your information ,you can also do this in one line that you can apply second `replaceAll` function on the output of first `replaceAll` function

```
s = s.replaceAll("[aeiouyYAEIOU]","").replaceAll("([^aeiouyAEIOU‌​Y])", ".$1");
```

Comment: It really works, I still don't get how $1 represent the consonant lol
Anyway thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @Franklin G. `$1` represents the `()` mean capture every consonant and remember it `([^aeiouyAEIOUY])` ,  so `() () ()` = `$1 $2 $3` , they are like index given to groups

Answer (score 0):

This example add "." before every consonant in a string.

```
public void test() {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");
    String text = "tour";
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(text);
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
        String substring = b.substring(i, i+1);
        if(isConsanantCharacter(substring)) {
            result.append("." + substring);
        } else {
            result.append(substring);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isConsanantCharacter(String character){
    String cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    return cons.contains(character);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "The Boy is a good boy";
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!(s.charAt(i) == 'a' || s.charAt(i) == 'e' || s.charAt(i) == 'i' || s.charAt(i) == 'o'
                || s.charAt(i) == 'u' || s.charAt(i) == 'A' || s.charAt(i) == 'E' || s.charAt(i) == 'I'
                || s.charAt(i) == 'U' || s.charAt(i) == 'O' || s.charAt(i) == ' ')) {
            newString.append('.');
        }
        newString.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(newString);
}
```

The output is:

```
.T.he .Bo.y i.s a .goo.d .bo.y
```

Answer (score 0):

en,if u can delete all of the vowels,it means the string is only made up of consonants now. 
pseudocode:

```
char[] chars=word.toCharArray；
String result；
for(int i;i<chars.length;i++){
    result=result+"."+chars[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Vowels {

    public static boolean isVowel(char input) {
        return (input == 'a' || input == 'e' || input == 'i' || input == 'o'
                || input == 'u' || input == 'A' || input == 'E' || input == 'I'
                || input == 'O' || input == 'U');
    }

    public static String addDots(char input) {

        if (!isVowel(input)) {
            return ".".concat("" + input);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "Hello";
        String newString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {         
            newString += addDots(inputString.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Output " + newString);

    }

}
```